# Match until second occurrence

Tags: php, regex

I've this string:

```
<h3>Test</h3><table></table><table></table><table></table>
```

My expected result:

```
<h3>Test</h3><table></table><table></table>
```

I've tried:

```
<h3>Test<\/h3>.+?(\/table>)
```

but it's lazy expression so the result will be:

```
<h3>Test</h3><table></table>
```

If I'm not wrong, I need to use HTML Dom Parser for this task, but just curious how to get it done using regex in this case.

Comment: Regardless of the approach, why do you have three empty tables? (Else accurate information might be relevant.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One exampel for using lazy expression is:

`"<h3>Test</h3>.+?</table>.+?</table>"`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're curious how to do this using regex, you can use a greedy quantifier instead with a Positive Lookahead.

```
preg_match('~<h3>Test</h3>.+(?=<table>)~', $text, $match);
echo $match[0]; //=> "<h3>Test</h3><table></table><table></table>"
```

But I am unclear if these are actual empty tables, if you have content between them:

```
preg_match('~<h3>Test</h3>(?:.*?</table>){2}~', $text, $match);
```

Using the right tool for the job:

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
     <h3>Test</h3><table></table><table></table><table></table>
');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$node  = $xpath->query('//table[last()]')->item(0);
$nnode = $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
echo $doc->saveHtml();
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/174375)

Comment: Hello, your answer works for my question but actually I want to get all contents until the end of second `</table>`. So if I've 4 times `<table></table>` then your regex will fail my requirement. My table is not empty since it's just an example. Thank you very much for your answer though.